# Connectable web parts - consuming from OOTB list view web part

Tags: web-part, connected-web-parts, list-view

I'm trying to create a custom web part that consumes from an OOTB list view web part's "Send Row of Data To" producer. The list has a lookup field to another list, and I need that value (the associated item in that other list) as a parameter in my custom web part.

**Resources I've looked through:**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469765.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597538.aspx
- [Which approach to use for connectable web parts?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6322/which-approach-to-use-for-connectable-web-parts)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.communication.irowprovider.aspx

What provider interface does the OOTB list view web part use? `IRowProvider` looked like a candidate, but it's listed as obsolete.

Hopefully, once I know what interface is being used, I can find the api and figure out how to drill into the row's data.

side note: Does anyone know where I can find the api for the OOTB list view web part? Perhaps it's documented in there? So far, I've only found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms448752.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.listviewwebpart_members.aspx), and they haven't been helpful.

**Solution:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.iwebpartrow.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried IWebPartRow?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.iwebpartrow.aspx

Comment: Indeed, this is the solution. I found that class after tinkering half an hour more. My frustration was making me desperate ~_~.